# What kind of insect is this? (seen in Goma, Democratic Republic of the Congo)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We recently (in November) saw this insect in Goma, DRC.

I would appreciate help identifying it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Common name is "Giant Water bug". These are hemipterans, in the family Belostomatidae. Images can be found here: https://bugguide.net/node/view/12796

Comment: Also, it's best practice to add another image of your species to confirm that you are talking about the same species. -1

Comment: Except for distinctively marked species, with insects, species identification often requires expert microscopic examination. Photo ID to species is generally impossible.

Comment: While I would absolutely agree with the other comments that you should elaborate and provide photos to allow your answer to be assessed, I'd certainly agree with this. I'd also explain in your answer that 'giant water bug' is the common name for the entire family, and therefore that while identification to species level may be impossible from the information provided, it's still correct to identify it as a giant water bug.

Comment: This answer still requires some elaboration to gain my upvote (and presumably upvotes from others as well).

Comment: @Bryan Krause. You must be into vertebrates. This is as close as you can get with photos of insects.

Comment: Tell us why you think that family, give information in your answer rather than a link, etc etc. I never asked you to give a specific species. Your answer as is does not meet the standards of the site.

Comment: I guess it might have something to do with the way this completely unique and unmistakable family looks. I did not take DNA samples from it, but I am as confident of my identification as I would be in calling a giraffe a mammal.

Comment: Karl, you've established yourself as an insect expert here, and your point about species-level IDing is understood and respected by many of us who frequent ID posts. However, I agree with @Bryan that your post (& others) could be improved by providing more detail (e.g., clues you used, characteristics (and sources/keys) the OP could use to ID to species, life histories, etc.) and/or a photo (even if it clearly states that it's just an example species from the genus/family). This post would qualify as a comment if the link died, but could serve as a great teaching aid with a bit more detail! :)